# How to map to CaseClass in scala

Tags: scala, functional-programming

i'm beginning scala i have this example case class

```
case class OrderItem(title: String,price: Long,quantity:Int,cover:Option[String],detailJson: String)
```

and i have List[OrderItem] and List[replaceregex]
i want to replace string to list[Orderitem] and i do

```
val s = OrderItem.flatMap(a => target.map (
      b =>
        if (a.detailJson.contains(start + "\"" + b.unit+ "\""))
          OrderItem(
            a.title,
            a.price,
            a.quantity,
            a.cover,
            a.detailJson.replaceFirst(startregex + b.unit, b.unitreplace))
        else None
      )).filter(_ != None)
```

and this return List[Product]

Can i Make it to List[Orderitem] from map ?
or this my code is bad solution can you tell me pls i'm begining

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This returns a `List[Product]` because your `map` operation returns either a `OrderItem` or a `None` and the most closer ancestor type for those 2 is `Product`.

You probably want to always return an `Option[OrderItem]` in your map and then keep only the defined items thanks to `collect`:

```scala
val s = orderItem
  .flatMap(a =>
    target.map( b =>
      if (...)
        Some(OrderItem(...)))
      else
        None
    )
    .collect { case Some(o) => o }
  )
```

But wait, as `Option` extends `Seq` you can actually just use `flatMap` and drop the `collect` like this:

```scala
val s = orderItem
  .flatMap(a =>
    target.flatMap(b =>
      if (...)
        Some(OrderItem(...)))
      else
        None
    )
  )
```

Comment: @PheemaphotChanyapisit please read [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)